# ES6 / Typescript: Stacking map and filter advanced array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

I have the following interfaces (minus details for clarity) in Ionic / Angular, which is why I use Typescript / ES6:

```
export interface Item {
  statusOfItem: string;
}
export interface checkin {
  items: Array<Item>;
}
export interface table {
  checkins: Array<Checkin>;
}
```

I need to write a function that the ingoing table object, but the checkins at the table all are filtered by their status.

Here is the function I came up with:

```
transformTable(table: Table, status: string): Table{
  let newTable: Table = table;
  newTable.checkins = table.checkins.map(
    checkin => {
      let newCheckin: Checkin = checkin;
      newCheckin.items = checkin.items.filter(
        item => item.statusOfItem == status
      );
      return newCheckin;
    }
  )
  return newTable;
}
```

I feel like using the new array functions like map etc. this can be done / written even more efficiently (e.g. without the `let`).

Comment: New array functions? Firefox has them since 2005.

Comment: Notice that assignment (or initialisation, in your `let` statement) does **not** copy the object.

Comment: @Bergi why is that? How can I copy the object with the let statement?

Comment: @Bergi You are right i noticed! How can I copy upon initialisation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to re-instanciate the function's parameters into new `let` variables. Just use them as they are.

```
transformTable(table: Table, status: string): Table{
  table.checkins = table.checkins.map(checkin => {
      checkin.items = checkin.items.filter( item => item.statusOfItem == status )
      return checkin
   })
  return table
}
```

This should work too. Anyway, I do that all the time and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) and [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) I ended up with this code:

```
private copyTableByStatus(table: Table, status: string): Table{
  // XXX: Weird, javascript can't deep copy. Object.assign() only creates
  // shallow copies. There should be something like Object.clone() ...
  let newTable: Table = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(table));
  newTable.checkins = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(table.checkins.map(
    checkin => {
      checkin.items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkin.items.filter(
        item => item.statusOItem == status
      )))
      return checkin;
    }
  )))
  return newTable;
}
```

Thank you to both of you. I didn't know, that javascript can't copy objects! :( That's so upsetting...

Comment: Small note: it might be cleaner to make use of the spread operator to copy objects. `let newTable = { ...table };`.

Comment: @Dieterg As far as I know after reading about this because of @Bergi 's comment `...table` would only do a shallow copy.